# iPhone UITabBar to iPad UISplitView

Tags: ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, universal

I am looking for suggestions on how to properly handle this. I have a iPhone app that uses a UITabBar. The tabbar simply loads 1 of 4 UIViews. I am porting this over to a universal app for use with the iPad. One of my views is perfect for the UISplitView, but the other 3 are not.

I understand the UISplitView must be the root controller so I would like to try to keep it that way. I guess the real questions is, what is the best way to switch between my views? Because for the iPhone app, the tabbar is the root controller and it is how you switch between views 1-4.

To help illustrate this:

View1 is a view to manage the processing of data.
View2 is used to manage the list of items to process (UISplitView)
View3 is for the app settings
View4 is for the about section.

When switching from portrait to landscape, on the iPad, unless you are on View2 I don't need the RootView of the UISplitView to show.

Please let me know if I am unclear on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like more of a UX issue than a coding issue. Your main views appear to be View1 and View2. My suggestion (without seeing the actual views) is the View2 should be your left view in the splitview in portrait mode, and View1 should be your main view. I would put buttons in the far right of the header/toolbar that pop modal dialogs for View3 and View4 as they are secondary actions to your application.